# create virtual model using other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models: Person and Employe.
I need to create object, that has records from Person exclude records from Employe, and use it as a model then (apply methods like "minimum").
Something like

```
People = Person - Employe
People.minimum
```

How can I do this?

Comment: If you have two **different** models, there is not way to subtract them. Use `employee` attribute in `Person` and then select records with such attribute `== false`, there are plenty of ways to do that (e. g. `scope`, by `sql` etc.)

Comment: Victor, one model relate to another as has_many/belongs_to

Answer (score 0):

People = set.new(Person).subtract(set.new(Employee))

or something similar

see : http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Set.html

Comment: Can't subtract apples from oranges

Comment: I was assuming that Person was a collection of people and Employee was also a collection of people ... but if that is not the case than you are correct and this solution wouldnt work